# SharePoint 2013 page layout does not show up in Page Layouts and Templates

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

OK, I confess! It has been a while that I have not used page layouts and especially now when we have got SPFx, and other nice things.

I created a page layout using Design Manger (SP 2013 :(). I have published the page layout, however it does not show up in: **Page layouts and site templates**.
Of course, nor in the Ribbon or when I create a new page.
Both HTML and aspx are present in the Master Page Gallery.

What am I missing or have forgotten? :)

Comment: Hi,
Have you set proper content type in page layout while adding?

Comment: I have used an OOTB CT as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow stpes:

**1. Please make sure the following features are actived**

- The top level Site sittings >> Site collection features >> SharePoint
  Server Publishing Infrastructure >> click on Active
  [image: SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure]
- The top level Site sittings >> Manage site features >> SharePoint
  Server Publishing >> click on Active
  [image: SharePoint Server Publishing]

**2.Create Page Layout Using Design Manager in SharePoint 2013 and publish it**
[image: New Page Layout]

**3.Create new page on the Pages Library**

- Go to Site Contents >> Pages Library >> Click New Document dropdown
  button to create new Page
  [image]
- When you create a new page, you can find the page layout template you
  just created in the Page Layout drop-down box
  [image]

……………………………………………………………………

Thanks, have a nice weekend！

Comment: thank you for your effort. I have already done what you have mentioned above. I believe there is a problem with the farm. I have tested it in my own farm and it works just fine.
Will get back once I have more information.

Comment: Thanks your reply. I am looking forward to your reply.                              
 I wish you all the best!